# Multiple jQuery on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have just started to learn jQuery and I think I am getting the hang to it, except this issue. I have a page of comments the user would like to delete. I am used to doing something like this:

```
$(function() {

$(".commentdeletebutton").click(function() {

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://myflashpics.com/process_deletecomment.php",
  data: $("#commentdeleteform").serialize(),
  success: function() {

    // Comment IDS are like this 'comment_123'
    var commentId  = $(comment_id).val();
    var commentDone = "comment_" + commentId;
    $(commentDone).fadeOut();


  }
 });
return false;
});
});
```

But since there are multiple instances of IDs, it's not working and nothing is happening.

Again, newbie here wondering what would be a better way to do this.

Thanks
Coulton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@php ,

First thing you should not have multiple ids on the DOM , this can cause several problems while parsing.

If you want to group them , give a generic class name like

```
classname + "ID"
```

later you can extrack the ID from the class and do your logic

you can do something like this

```
var className=$(this).attr('class');            
        var ID = className.replace(/yourclassname(\d+)/, "$1");
```

Comment: How do I "extrack the ID from the class and do your logic"? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks so much.. It almost works! Quick question: How do I fadeOut a id if I give it a `var`, not a value? Here's what I have: `var commentDone = "comment__25"; $(commentDone).fadeOut();` and nothing happens. If I do this: `var commentDone = "comment__25"; document.getElementById(commentDone).innerHTML = ""; $(commentDone).fadeOut();` then it changes the content in the box. Please help!

Comment: @php , you should provide a # symbol if that is id...$('#'+commentDone).fadeOut()

Answer (score 2):

Instead of id attribute use class class attribute.
ID's are unique.

Comment: I have many delete forms on one page. If I make them all the same CLASS, how will I know the ID posted to it?

Comment: @php , make your class name dynamic with name and id , and you should be albe to differentiate later by breaking the class and id ...

Answer (score 2):

IDs should always be unique.  Consider adding something more to your IDs to make them unique.

Comment: Ok. So my delete buttons will be like deletecomment_idnumber? How will I know the IDNUMBER... If that question makes sense.

Comment: @php , .val gives the value of the input right , where are you getting the id from ?? is id unique in your case

Answer (score 2):

Somehow related to what @kobe says, I think your best approach is to generate those IDs based on a prefix (like myComment-) and the id in the DB. This way you would end with elements identified by myComment-1, myComment-2, ..., myComment-n .

Then, when you should use a selector for each element that starts with "myComment" (look at the selectors documentation on the jQuery docs) and set it the "click" handler. Accessing $(this) should give you the clicked element and you can get the ID, remove the 'comment-' section programmatically, and once again, retrieve or perform the action or get the required attributes for the original ID.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, it's not clear where `comment_id` comes from.

If `$(".commentdeletebutton")` is inside some container, or next to the element you need to fadeOut, you could use some `.parent()` or `.next()` selector, without need any ID.

PS: it seems that you are not telling `http://myflashpics.com/process_deletecomment.php` which comment it must delete either.

Comment: Yes, that's also my issue because there are multiple IDS on the same page.

Comment: As the other guys said, you must not have duplicated IDs in a page. But, if you already have a way to identify every comment (I guess you have it), I don't see why you have duplicate IDs.